# Googlewebauthorizationbroker.AuthorizeAsync on IIS .Net RunTime Error

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I use  `Googlewebauthorizationbroker.AuthorizeAsync()` to get token. I use "process" on website and to call ConsloeApp to get Google Calender's data. It is on visual studio(2017) work perfectly, but when I put in IIS, it is not open browser to authorize and the IIS get .Net RunTime ERROR.

This my code. Hope can get some solution with this problem.

```
Public Sub  Main(args As String())

    Dim userID As String = "xxx"
    Dim Credential As UserCredential

    Dim Stream As New FileStream("~\credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

    Dim credPath As String = "~\token.json"
    Credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(Stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        userID,
        CancellationToken.None,
        New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result

    Dim oService As CalendarService = New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With
    {
            .HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
            .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
    })

    Fun_List(oService)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

And this is the error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzd4c.jpg)

My question might like this issue.

[GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker won't open browser when running on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843046/googlewebauthorizationbroker-wont-open-browser-when-running-on-iis)

[Google Auth runs in Visual studio but hangs when deployed to IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064047/google-auth-runs-in-visual-studio-but-hangs-when-deployed-to-iis)

Comment: Sorry.my mistake. So What should I need  to provided? I don't understand.

Comment: You say you got a runtime error. Please provide the full exception and stack trace.

Comment: @John I provide the image about error message,thanks

Comment: I'll retract my downvote, but ideally should should provide that information as text in your question. The closest (albeit C#) question I found that's similar to yours is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581756/google-apis-json-newtonsoftjsonserializer-throw-an-exception).

Comment: My question might like this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835914/googlewebauthorizationbroker-is-not-working-from-iis-host#new-answer?newreg=4a12ea53ad0546aa938f5598e8835e6e). But this doesn't have solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is used for installed applications. It will open the browser window on the machine running the code.  In the instance where you are running it in Visual studio it works fine but as soon as you try to host it it will try to open the browser window on the web server which wont work.

You need to be using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow which was designed for use with web applications.  You can find an example [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) unfortunately its C# i dont know of any VB samples for the google .net client library.

```
private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
            });
```

Comment: The C# is not a problem, I can translate. I know this way with MVC. My project had use this way now. So, `Googlewebauthorizationbroker.AuthorizeAsync()` look like is not the best way on web server. Thanks your solution.

Comment: I had find the VB sample code with `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067405/google-oauth-approval-prompt-for-net) or [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2015065.aspx?Google+Calendar+V3+in+ASP+Net+VB+Net). If anyone need it.